# Neither brasero or Xfburn recognizes the blank disc

Tags: 12.04, burning, brasero

ever since I updated my ubuntu 12.04 [NOT upgrade], my linux install can no longer burn discs. I can't seem to find a thread on how to fix this.

Neither brasero or Xfburn recognizes the blank disc, so they are only giving me the option to burn an image onto my HDD.  Therefore, I believe this to be a system level problem as opposed to an app problem.

I'm pretty sure my hardware is good because it was burning discs UNTIL I updated.

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: I've experienced several big problems with Brasero, and then switched to K3B - it works fine. I recommend you to do the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common cdrdao cdparanoia cue2toc dvdauthor dvd+rw-tools genisoimage wodim
```

Comment: what exactly will this command do ?

Comment: my laptop can read the CD-R but can NOT write / burn to CD-R. Please help